# How to set hyper parameters for a Variational Quantum Classifier (qiskit)?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am trying to implement a Variational Quantum Classifier using qiskit's VQC. I have set the feature map to `ZZFeatureMap` and am using the `RealAmplitudes` ansatz. I am using `cross_entropy` loss function and `ADAM` optimiser. One more parameter that VQC requires is a QuantumInstance object and this I have set to `aer_simulator` with `1024 shots`.
The code and instructions I followed is in this [qiskit's tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/02_neural_network_classifier_and_regressor.html).

When I try to train the classifier, it running for a different number of iterations each time. **Is there a way to set minimum number of iterations ? and how are iterations different from shots ?**

Also, how can I set the learning rate for the algorithm ? Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VQC consists of a feedback loop of quantum and classical processor, where the loss function is evaluated on a quantum computer and the classical part suggests new parameters. The number of shots is the number of samples the quantum computer does to estimate the expectation values (-> the loss function). The number of iterations is the number of times the classical part updates the parameters.

The settings you want to specify are part of the *classical optimizer*, in your case ADAM. Following the tutorial you linked, I'm assuming you're constructing the algorithm as

```
# construct feature map, ansatz, and optimizer
feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(num_inputs)
ansatz = RealAmplitudes(num_inputs, reps=1)
optimizer = ADAM()

# construct variational quantum classifier
vqc = VQC(feature_map=feature_map,
          ansatz=ansatz,
          loss='cross_entropy',
          optimizer=optimizer,
          quantum_instance=quantum_instance,
          callback=callback_graph)
```

You can pass your settings into the `ADAM` class, for instance to set the learning rate

```
optimizer = ADAM(lr=your_desired_learning_rate)
```

The number of iterations depends on the convergence and I don't think you can set a minimum number of them. However you can set a lower tolerance which will lead to more iterations. For example

```
optimizer = ADAM(lr=0.01, tol=1e-7)
```

You can find more on that in the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.ADAM.html?highlight=adam#qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.ADAM).

Comment: Thank you, this clears up a lot of things.